# Gausian mixture model implementation for background subtraction in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I've tried MOG and MOG2 and difference between frames but no one are giving me good results and i don't find any GMM implementation of background using python kindly help if u have any learning sources.

and is there any way to use vibe background subtraction using python openCv

Answer (score 1):

Create MOG2 bgs outside loop of frames.

```
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(9,9))
    fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=100,varThreshold=10,detectShadows=True)
```

Use gaussian blur like so

```
        # Apply background sub on slightly blurred frame
        blurFrame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(9,9),0)
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(blurFrame, kernel, -1)
```

Apply this every frame after applying background subtraction.

see more at the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html)